# I need to build a ANN for my research where i want to input 2 feature vectors and predict if the two images are matching or not

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, sequential

I need to build a ANN for my research where i want to input 2 feature vectors and predict if the two images are matching or not. i tried using keras sequential model but i need to know whats the most suitable among keras functional API and keras sequential model.

Comment: You need to use Siamese nets, which cannot be built with the sequential API. You need to use the functional API.

Comment: thanks a lot! im a beginner in python. ill try that